# Can I describe time as "organic"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word to describe the other face or trait of time which is not man-made and has no time-stamp to it.

A (very) general example is that there are "morning" and "night" people who react (to time) and perform differently at different hour of the day.

Is "organic" a fitting word to use?

I would like to say something along the lines of "time is an organic resource". Would that be wrong?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What are you actually trying to say by "time is an organic resource"? It may be there's other words that are more fitting.

Comment: The kind of alternative to "man made" or "artificial construction" you're looking for is *natural*, and its synonyms. The word *organic* doesn't work.

Comment: [circadian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circadian_rhythm)?

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be a tenuous way to use it:

> relating to or derived from living matter.
>
> (of food or farming methods) produced or involving production without the use of chemical fertilizers, pesticides, or other artificial chemicals.

I don't think it would make sense to refer to time in this fashion.

Answer (score 1):

As Dan Bron says, the natural word to use here is "natural". "Time is a natural phenomenon. Measuring time with a clock is a human invention."

You COULD use the word "organic" to describe this, but you would have to explain it. When you're trying to make a distinction, you often have to explain what you mean, and then can say, "for the rest of this article/book/web page/whatever, I will use the word 'frambar' to express this distinction." Or whatever word, of course.